# Vlookup Range of Data to Another Sheet Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba and wonder if I could do vlookup range of data from column C in sheet 1 to column D in sheet 2.

This is my current code and when I run it, VBA doesn't give any run time error nor any results as well:

```
Sub look()
    Dim lw As Range
    Set lw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NO PK").Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown)
    
    For i = 3 To lw
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetsFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("NO PK").Cells(i, 1).Value, Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A:P"), 16, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

I wish to make it dynamic by using for next loop. But, I'm open to other ideas. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Step through the code and check the value of `Rows.Count` and `lw`, they are probably not what you expect.

Comment: Try `xlUp` instead of `xlDown`.

Comment: You are writing to the wrong worksheet i.e. it should be `Worksheets("NO PK").Cells(i, 3)  ...`>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A VBA VLookup

[image]

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LookupInSheet5()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet5")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Columns("A:P")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("NO PK")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 3 To dlRow
        dws.Cells(i, "C").Value _
            = Application.VLookup(dws.Cells(i, "A").Value, srg, 16, 0)
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "Lookup has finished.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry i gave slightly wrong directions. I have changed sws to "NO PK" and dws to "Sheet5". But when i run it, it returns to N/A. Do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: fyi, column 16 consists of number and text in each cells

Comment: `#N/A` means that no match was found i.e. a result (return value) is **N**ot **A**vailable (see cell `'NO PK'!C8`). Study the screenshot to figure out what is being looked up and what is returned e.g. cell `'NO PK'!A3` contains `2` which is found in `Sheet5!A7` so `B` from `Sheet5!P7` is returned in `'NO PK'!C3`. Why don't you share the screenshots of your worksheets (hide the irrelevant columns)?

Comment: I've figured it out. My lookup range wasn't in the first column of Sheet "NO PK". I changed srg to start from column ("C:P"). Overall your code is very helpful and easy to follow. Thank you so much for your help :)